# AFNetworking Expected content type error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I am getting the json string in failure block

```
 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.vinipost.com/Services/Update/UpdateService.asmx/GetPropSubType?"];
        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];

        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

            NSLog(@"%@", JSON);
        } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
            NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
        }];
        [operation start];
```

Output:

```
Request Failed with Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "text/json",
    "text/javascript",
    "application/json",
    "text/html"
)}, got text/plain" UserInfo=0x71521a0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=[{"PropTypId":1,"PropCatId":1,"PropTyp":"Flat/ Condo"}.......**
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is clear:
the web service is returning a wrong content type.
The content type should be one of these:

> "text/json",
>       "text/javascript",
>       "application/json",
>       "text/html"

But it returns

> text/plain

Moreover, if you look at the http response, it returns HTML TAGS inside it, so AFNetworking is not able to parse.

If this page:

```
http://www.vinipost.com/Services/Update/UpdateService.asmx/GetPropSubType?
```

is under your control, correct the behavior removing html tags and changing the content type

Comment: @LombaX- ok, So how to deal with it

Comment: change the code of UpdateService.asmx web page to return a correct JSON response, with text/plain content type. I can't help you with ASP

Answer (score 10):

You need to add this line before operation

```
[AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:
                            [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"]];
```

Comment: -the problem was from server side as the expected answers explains

Comment: This is also a correct answer.  It is not correct to state that 'the problem was from the server side' - the problem was specified as an error message occurring and therefore could have been fixed at either the server or client end to provide a working solution.

Comment: @CarlosP- i tried stanislav first but getting the same issue. couldn't fix it on client side.

Comment: It's strange, I fixed such issue in previous project and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

In AFNetworking, you have to create NSURLRequest with the help of AFHTTPClient(So first you have to create AFHTTPClient and have to set some properties for this object) like below

`AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[httpClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.vinipost.com/"]];`

```
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
```

now if depends of GET/POST or any other type request you need to set parameter I consider it as POST Request, so set the Parameter dict and set all required Key Value pairs properly.if no parameters required you can pass Parameters as `nil`

```
NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"Services/Update/UpdateService.asmx/GetPropSubType?" parameters:params];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"%@",JSON);

                                     }
                                     failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"Error MSG = %@",error);
                                     }];

[operation start];
```

hope this will work for you :)