# AFNetworking version 2 content-type error

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, afjsonrequestoperation

I'm attempting to make an iphone app that will interact with a particular JIRA server.  I've got the following code to log in:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/auth/latest/session/"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"username\":\"%@\",\"password\":\"%@\"}", username, password];
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept" ];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:
    ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);

    }
 ];
 [operation start];
```

But it's giving me the following error having to do with Content-Type:

```
ERROR: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011
"Request failed: unsupported media type (415)"
UserInfo=0x8cd6540
{
  NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/auth/latest/session/,
  NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unsupported media type (415),
  NSUnderlyingError=0x8c72e70
  "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html",
```

I'm not sure what the problem is.  I found **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648090/afnetworking-expected-content-type-error)**, which I thought might be a similar problem, but the answers say to either use the `AFJSONRequestOperation` class (which I can't because I'm using AFNetworking version 2, which doesn't have that class), or to fix it on the server side (which I also can't for obvious reasons).

What can I fix this error when I can't fix the server side and I can't use `AFJSONRequestOperation`?

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. BTW, it's inadvisable to build JSON with `stringWithFormat` (if password had certain characters in it, it would fail). Better to use `NSDictionary *postDictionary = @{@"username":username,@"password":password};` and then use `NSData *postBody = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDictionary options:0 error:&error];` to create the `NSData` for `setHTTPBody`. Or in AF 2.0 use `POST` and `AFJSONRequestSerializer` (in AF 1.x use `AFHTTPClient` with `parameterEncoding` of `AFJSONParameterEncoding`), and it will convert the dictionary to JSON for you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If using AFNetworking 2.0, you can use the `POST` method, which simplifies this a bit:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username":username, @"password":password};
[manager POST:@"https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/auth/latest/session/" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

This does the creation of the request, setting its `Content-Type` according to the `requestSerializer` setting, and encodes the JSON for you. One of the advantages of AFNetworking is that you can get out of the weeds of constructing and configuring `NSURLRequest` objects manually.

---

By the way, the "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" error means that regardless of what you were expecting to receive (e.g. JSON), you received HTML response. This is very common: Many server errors (e.g. the server informing you that the request was malformed, etc.) generate HTML error messages. If you want to see that HTML, in your `failure` block, simply log the `operation.responseString`.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the problem is that this one line:

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept" ];
```

Should be

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type" ];
```

The error is now solved.  (**Edit**: I should have both, see CouchDeveloper's comment.)

**EDIT**
Rob's solution is better, so I'm going with it.  I had actually tried a similar solution to what he shows, but where he had the line,

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

I had the line:

```
[manager.requestSerializer
    setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

...which didn't work.  Kudos to Rob for getting it to work!

Comment: You may need both: with the header "Accept" you specify what kind of media type you want to receive when there is a response. With header "Content-Type" you specify the media type which you are sending. The "Content-Type" header SHOULD (really should) be specified in your request.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Thanks, that helps me comprehend this better.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in AFNetworking 2.0 and the solution was that I had to make sure I set the AFHTTPRequestSerializer type (In case your request is JSON) the it should be like this.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *myHTTPManager = ...
[myManager setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];
```

You have to set both `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` and `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using default written class **AFAppDotNetAPIClient** and you face this error. Must add **responseSerializer**. see your shared method should look like -

```
+ (instancetype)sharedClient {

static AFAppDotNetAPIClient *_sharedClient = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    _sharedClient = [[AFAppDotNetAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:AFAppDotNetAPIBaseURLString]];
    _sharedClient.securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
    _sharedClient.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
});
return _sharedClient;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code.

```
operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
```